# How to subset the next column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(intro = c("bob","bob","bob"),
           intro_score = c("Excellent","Excellent","Good"),
           method = c("sally","sally","sally"),
           method_score = c("Excellent","Excellent","Excellent"),
           result = c("Norman","Norman","Norman"),
           result_score = c("Good","Good","Good"))
```

If I want to look for "bob" in this dataframe, how do I return the column next to "bob" (intro_score only), assuming I'm not sure if "bob" is in here. Say, if I were to look for "ken", the result should be null. If I were to look for "Norman", the result should return result_score.

I have tried something like this:

```
name <- "bob"

df_name <- df %>%
  if (str_detect(intro, name)) {
    select((which(colnames==str_detect(intro, name)))+1)
  } else {}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what if "bob" is in two columns? or even three?

Comment: also do you need what is contained in the next column or do you need the column name?

Comment: Good question. Typically "bob" will not be in 2 columns in the same row (an observation). However, "bob" may be in a different column (e.g., method) in another row/observation. I need what is contained in the next column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reshape your data into time (intro, method, result), name, and score.

```
df2 <- reshape(df, direction = "long", varying = list(c(1,3,5), c(2,4,6)), v.names = c("name", "score"), times = c("intro", "method", "result"))    
df2[df2$name == "Norman", "score"]
```

Comment: you know you could just do `reshape(df,matrix(1:ncol(df),2),dir="long")`

Comment: Thank you, Ben! That absolutely worked for me! I may not have asked the right question.

Comment: Glad to hear. I appreciate the other answers and gained some knowledge myself. If you feel appropriate, feel free to upvote or accept answer(s): https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

using base R if you need the names you could do:

```
names(df[unique(which(df=="bob",TRUE)[,2]+1)])
[1] "intro_score"
```

or if you need the column values, you do:

```
df[unique(which(df=="bob",TRUE)[,2]+1)]

intro_score
1   Excellent
2   Excellent
3        Good
```

Comment: This is what I would have done `names(df)[unique(which(df=="bob",TRUE)[,2]+1)]` very small difference that your answer. +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(purrr)
search_person <- "bob"
colnames(df)[which(map_lgl(df,~all(.x == search_person))) + 1]
```

```r
"intro_score"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `select_if`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
df %>% 
   select_if(~ any(. == "bob")) %>%
   names %>%
   match(., names(df)) %>% 
   add(1) %>% 
   names(df)[.]
#[1] "intro_score"
```