# Select data.table values based on a vector of column indexes

Tags: r, select, data.table

How to select values from `data.table` based on a vector of column indexes.

I have an integer vector of the same length as the number of rows in a data.table:

```r
set.seed(100)
col.indexes <- sample(c(1:4), 150, replace = TRUE)
```

How to create a vector of values based on it? e.g. this without `for` loop:

```
iris <- setDT(iris)
res <- c()
for(i in 1:150) {
  res[i] <- iris[i, .SD, .SDcols = col.indexes[i]]
}
res <- unlist(res)
```

this is loosely based on this question: 
[How to subset the next column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58312658/how-to-subset-the-next-column-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do a group by sequence of rows and extract the values

```
res <- iris[, col1 := col.indexes][, .SD[[col1[1]]], 1:nrow(iris)]$V1
```

---

Or in `base R`, it can be done in a vectorized way

```
iris <- setDF(iris)
iris[1:4][cbind(seq_len(nrow(iris)), col.indexes)]
```

Comment: For reference - see FR 657 discussion on making the ```base R``` an option in ```data.table```  https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/657

Answer (score 3):

Here's a complicated answer using `melt` and a join. Using a `data.frame` is better for this:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(iris)

dt[, ID := .I]
dt[, Species := NULL]

melt(dt, id.vars = 'ID'
     )[, variable := as.integer(variable)
       ][data.frame(col.indexes, ID = seq_len(150))
         , on = .(ID, variable = col.indexes)
         , value
         ]
```

Here's @akrun's base method doing awesome:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 13
  expression           min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
  <bch:expr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
1 akrun_dt          4.49ms   4.78ms     190.   107.84KB
2 akrun_base         122us  127.4us    7575.     8.44KB
3 cole_melt         3.99ms   4.24ms     233.   271.41KB
4 Pavo_diag         3.32ms   3.45ms     283.   449.44KB
5 OP_loop          83.08ms  84.03ms      11.9    4.86MB
6 OP_loop_dt_mod    1.32ms   1.36ms     712.    13.76KB
7 OP_loop_mat_mod  373.9us  389.2us    2472.    17.17KB
```

I also did 1E5 rows per @Bulat's comment. I got an error with @PavoDive's method so I excluded it.

```
# A tibble: 7 x 13
  expression           min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
  <bch:expr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 akrun_dt           2.19s    2.19s    0.456     6.58MB    1.37      1     3
2 akrun_base        2.73ms   2.88ms   58.5       8.79MB    7.63     46     6
3 cole_melt        30.53ms  33.63ms   29.6      17.79MB    1.97     15     1
4 OP_loop            1.07m    1.07m    0.0156    3.16GB    0.810     1    52
5 OP_loop_df_mod  991.45ms 991.45ms    1.01       3.3MB    2.02      1     2
6 OP_loop_dt_mod     1.07s    1.07s    0.930      3.3MB    1.86      1     2
7 OP_loop_mat_mod 218.95ms 235.98ms    4.29      4.58MB    1.43      3     1
```

Then I upped it to 1E7 rows:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression   min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr> <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 akrun_base 2.21s  2.21s     0.452   877.4MB    0.904     1     2      2.21s
2 cole_melt  4.88s  4.88s     0.205    1.71GB    0.410     1     2      4.88s
```

Complete code for benchmarks:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(100)
ind <- 1E5

col.indexes <- sample(c(1:4), ind, replace = TRUE)
dt1 <- as.data.table(iris[sample(nrow(iris), ind, replace = T), ])

bench::mark(
  akrun_dt = {
    dt <- copy(dt1)
    dt[, col1 := col.indexes][, .SD[[col1[1]]], 1:nrow(dt)]$V1
  }
  ,
  akrun_base = {
    DF <- copy(dt1)
    setDF(DF)
    DF[1:4][cbind(seq_len(nrow(DF)), col.indexes)]
  }
  ,
  cole_melt = {
    dt <- copy(dt1)
    dt[, ID := .I]
    dt[, Species := NULL]

    melt(dt, id.vars = 'ID'
    )[, variable := as.integer(variable)
      ][data.frame(col.indexes, ID = seq_len(ind))
        , on = .(ID, variable = col.indexes)
        , value
        ]
  }
  # ,Pavo_diag = {
  #   diag(as.matrix(dt1[, .SD, .SDcols = col.indexes]))
  # }
  ,
  OP_loop = {
    res <- c()

    for(i in seq_len(ind)) {
      res[i] <- dt1[i, .SD, .SDcols = col.indexes[i]]
    }
    unlist(res)
  }
  ,
  OP_loop_df_mod = {
    sapply(seq_len(ind), function(i) DF[[col.indexes[i]]][i])
  }
  ,
  OP_loop_dt_mod = {
    sapply(seq_len(ind), function(i) dt1[[col.indexes[i]]][i])
  }
  ,
  OP_loop_mat_mod = {
    mat <- as.matrix(DF[1:4])
    colnames(mat) <- NULL
    unlist(lapply(seq_len(ind), function(i) mat[i, col.indexes[i]]), use.names = F)
  }
)
```

Comment: I think `data.table` benchmarks start to makes sense on over 10^5 rows

Comment: @Bulat see edit. ```base``` is still the way to go for this.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting that there seems to be no `native` way to do this in `data.table`. I was actually expecting it to work in a similar way as `base` does, but could not make it.

Answer (score 2):

I see another option:

```
res2 <- diag(as.matrix(iris[, .SD, .SDcols = col.indexes]))
all.equal(res2, res)

[1] TRUE
```